# Exceptions in code to continue concatenating files

Tags: python

So I'm concatenating 3 xlsx files into one. But sometimes, one of the files can be blank, while the other have content. 
This code stop concatening the files even though the other have content.

I have this code in python:

```
  for items_1 in path:
            if items_1.endswith('file1.blastn.xlsx'):
                file1 = pd.read_excel(items_1, sep='\t', names=['type', 'ID', 'type2', 'Name_file1'])
            elif items_1.endswith('file2.blastn.xlsx'):
                file2 = pd.read_excel(items_1, sep='\t', names=['type', 'ID', 'type2', 'Name_file2'])
            elif items_1.endswith('file3.blastn.xlsx'):
                file3 = pd.read_excel(items_1, sep='\t', names=['type', 'ID', 'type2', 'Name_file3'])
            elif items_1.endswith('file4.blastn.xlsx'):
                file4 = pd.read_excel(items_1, sep='\t', names=['type', 'ID', 'type2', 'Name_file4'])
            all_table = pd.concat([file1, file2,file3,file4], axis=1, join='outer', ignore_index=False)
            all_table_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(all_table)
            next_in.to_excel(str(header_file) + '.final.xlsx')
```

So I want an exception that can continue concatenating the files despite the blank file. 
Can somenone explain to me, an exception that continues to do this to the rest of the files. 
Thanks

Comment: The code only sets one of `file2`, `file3`, or `file4`. You can't concatenate them all together. And should the lines beginning with `all_table =` be outside the `elif`?

Comment: Can you provide a a better example with correct indentation, please?

Comment: Sorry, I already corrected the indentation...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a try/except?

```
for items_1 in path:
    try:
            if items_1.endswith('file1.blastn.xlsx'):
                file1 = pd.read_excel(items_1, sep='\t', names=['type', 'ID', 'type2', 'Name_file1'])
            elif items_1.endswith('file2.blastn.xlsx'):
                file2 = pd.read_excel(items_1, sep='\t', names=['type', 'ID', 'type2', 'Name_file2'])
            elif items_1.endswith('file3.blastn.xlsx'):
                file3 = pd.read_excel(items_1, sep='\t', names=['type', 'ID', 'type2', 'Name_file3'])
            elif items_1.endswith('file4.blastn.xlsx'):
                file4 = pd.read_excel(items_1, sep='\t', names=['type', 'ID', 'type2', 'Name_file4'])
            all_table = pd.concat([file1, file2,file3,file4], axis=1, join='outer', ignore_index=False)
            all_table_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(all_table)
            next_in.to_excel(str(header_file) + '.final.xlsx')
    except:
        continue
```